# Checkbox binding to change the ListView's items source

Tags: c#, wpf, observer-pattern

I am using a checkbox to filter some components on my `ListView` by changing the variable's content which is bound to this `ListView`:

**C#**

```cs
#region Constructor

void CreateAllParts()
{
    // GetParts() returns List<Part>. Now we can pour it's results 
    // using the following select in List<EditPartViewModel> on the 
    // fly.
    // allpvms: All Part View Models.
    allpvms = _partRepository.GetParts().Select(p => new EditPartViewModel(p)).ToList();

    foreach (EditPartViewModel cvm in allpvms)
    {
        cvm.PropertyChanged += this.OnPartViewModelPropertyChanged;
    }

    this.AllParts = new ObservableCollection<EditPartViewModel>(allpvms);
    this.AllParts.CollectionChanged += this.OnCollectionChanged;
}


void LoadErrorParts()
{
    if (_errorParts)
    {
        this.AllParts = new ObservableCollection<EditPartViewModel>(allpvms.Where(p => p.Price == null));
        this.AllParts.CollectionChanged += this.OnCollectionChanged;
    }
    else
    {
        this.AllParts = new ObservableCollection<EditPartViewModel>(allpvms);
        this.AllParts.CollectionChanged += this.OnCollectionChanged;
    }
}

#endregion // Constructor

#region Public Interface

/// <summary>
/// Returns a collection of all the EditPartViewModel objects.
/// </summary>
public ObservableCollection<EditPartViewModel> AllParts
{
    get
    {
        return _allParts;
    }
    set
    {
        _allParts = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("AllParts");
    }
}

public bool ErrorParts
{
    get
    {
        return _errorParts;
    }
    set
    {
        _errorParts = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ErrorParts");
        LoadErrorParts();
    }
}

#endregion // Public Interface
```

**XAML**

```xaml
<CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" 
          IsChecked="{Binding ErrorParts, Mode=TwoWay}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Right"
          Content="Parts with Error"
          />

<ListView
  AlternationCount="2"
  d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:MockViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
  ItemsSource="{Binding AllParts}"
  >
  <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
      <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick" />
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
  </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

`ListView`s content get collected by a `DataTemplate` in the `Resources`.

Is the way I use the binding concept look okay? Any corrections or "good practice" methods I should consider when doing similar procedures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably bind `ItemsSource` to `CollectionView`, instead of binding to `ObservableCollection`. This way you don't have to recreate collection every time you want to apply your filter. May look like this:

```
//constructor
Parts = new ObservableCollection<EditPartViewModel>(allpvms);
PartsCollectionView = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Parts);

...............

public ListCollectionView PartsCollectionView { get; private set; }

public bool ErrorParts
{
    get
    {
        return _errorParts;
    }
    set
    {
        _errorParts = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ErrorParts");
        PartsCollectionView.Filter = value ? (Predicate<Object>)(p => ((EditPartViewModel)p).Price == null) : null;
    }
}
```

Also if your viewmodles can contain errors, you should probably move your error-checking logic inside those viewmodels. So instead of writing `p.Price == null` you would write `p.HasErrors` or something.

You should also indicate, that `ErrorParts` is actually a bool property, unlike `AllParts` which is a collection. `DisplayErrors` or `ShowErrors` or `FilterErrors` etc. are better names for this property in my opinion.

Comment: That's why I like CodeReview. There is a way of doing things and there is a better way. Naming was a quick draft type of thing to see if I can make it work. Great suggestions. Applied them both and worked like a charm. 
Also wondering if I can use the same technique for implementing a search box for my `listview` content? 
and also curious (might be irrelevant) where did you learn or read about `CollectionViews`? if there is an example I love to follow it to learn more.

Comment: @Mehrad, you definitely can. However in this case instead of re-setting `Filter` property every time your search creterea changes, you might want to imeplement some general filtering method, which will depend on some external parameters (you will have to manually call `ListCollectionView.Refresh()` whenever those parameters change though). As for your last question: i am not sure. :) Probably stumbled upon it on StackOverflow one day. Check out this link for examples: http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/collectionviewsource/ + there is decent documentation on `CollectionViewSource` on msdn